# Enumerate the first column in tabular

Tags: tables, enumerate

Given the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

        \begin{tabular}{llllllll}
            
            
            \(\indent (1)\) & \( \mathrm{A}\) & \(\Rightarrow\) & \( \mathrm{B}\) & ~  & ~ \\    [5pt]  
            \(\indent (2)\) & \( \mathrm{C}\) & \(\Rightarrow\) & \( \mathrm{D}\) & ~  & ~ \\    [5pt]  
            \(\indent (3)\) &  \(  \mathrm{E}\) & \(\Leftrightarrow \) & \( \mathrm{F}\) & \, \({\Large \&}\)  &  \(\lnot \mathrm{G}\) \\ [5pt]  
            \(\indent(4)\) & \( \mathrm{H}\) & \(\Leftrightarrow\) & \(\models \mathrm{I}\) &  \, \({\Large \&}\) & \(\lnot \mathrm{J}\) 
            
            
        \end{tabular}
        
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to obtain this via enumerate, so that an active item command may be used for the first column?

The goal is to use such a construction inside theorem environments, and it will for that reason on occasions be useful to refer to the numbered sub-theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it is not clear why you use table for your math terms. Result is, according to my opinion, quite ugly.

Using `enumerate` list I would ad in-line path expression without table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item   $ \mathrm{A} \Rightarrow    \mathrm{B}$ 
\item   $ \mathrm{C} \Rightarrow    \mathrm{D}$
\item   $ \mathrm{E} \Leftrightarrow\mathrm{F}\hphantom{\models}
                                                     \wedge\lnot\mathrm{G}$
\item   $ \mathrm{H} \Leftrightarrow\;\models\mathrm{I}\wedge\lnot\mathrm{J}$
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the tabular environment to obtain better alignment. If there is no such solution, I will, as you, just use enumerate.